# Customer retention rate in snowflake

Tags: sql, statistics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, analysis

I have this formula for the customer retention rate but kinda stuck in translating it into a sql code in snowflake:

**Customer Retention rate: number of customers who purchased in the past AND in the period of [last 30 days] / number of customers who have purchased in the past [not including last 30 days]**

Comment: it is generally preferred that you show you data, and expected output, and show SQL that you have tried, and which part you are stuck on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if we check for each customer if they have "old sales" and "new sales"

```
select customer_id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, min_date < (current_date()-30) as old_sales, max_date >= (current_date()-30) as new_sales
from values
    (1,'2022-05-01'),
    (2,'2022-05-01'),
    (2,'2022-04-01'),
    (3,'2022-04-01'),
    (4,'2022-04-01'),
    (4,'2022-03-01')
    t(customer_id, date)
group by 1
```

we get:

| CUSTOMER_ID | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE | OLD_SALES | NEW_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-01 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-01 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-01 | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-04-01 | TRUE | FALSE |

we then want to count both as true for the top, and trop/false for the bottom, we can use:

```
select count_if(old_sales and new_sales) as top
    ,count_if(old_sales and  new_sales=false) as bottom
    ,div0(top, bottom) as rention
from (
    select customer_id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, min_date < (current_date()-30) as old_sales, max_date >= (current_date()-30) as new_sales
    from values
        (1,'2022-05-01'),
        (2,'2022-05-01'),
        (2,'2022-04-01'),
        (3,'2022-04-01'),
        (4,'2022-04-01'),
        (4,'2022-03-01')
        t(customer_id, date)
    group by 1
);
```

and get:

| TOP | BOTTOM | RENTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.5 |

thus with a `data_table` as our source we can use:

```
select div0(count_if(old_sales and new_sales), count_if(old_sales and  new_sales=false)) as rention
from (
    select 
        min(date) < (current_date()-30) as old_sales, 
        max(date) >= (current_date()-30) as new_sales
    from data_table
    group by customer_id
);
```

to get the magic 50%